# Scala recursive head tail pattern match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

This is a sample scala code-

```
def foo(n : Int, ls : List[Int]) : Int =
ls match {
    case Nil => n
    case hd :: tl => hd*foo(n-1,tl)
}
```

If I pass `foo(7,List(1,2,-2,2))` gives me **-24** But I don't understand how this works, can anyone help me understand how the recursion works here?

Comment: This is rec but not tailrec for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not totally sure what you're asking, this may be overly elaborate.

In the `match`:

- `case Nil` will match (and only match) an empty list
- `case hd :: tl` will destructure the list (the exact mechanism of how/why this works is beyond the scope of this answer) with the value `hd` being the first element of the list and the value `tl` being a list containing every element after the first

So, proceeding with the substitution model of evaluation, we end up with:

- `foo(7, List(1, 2, -2, 2))`: the list (`ls`) is non-empty, so the second match clause matches and the result is
- `1 * foo(6, List(2, -2, 2))`: the list is non-empty, so the second match clause matches and the result is (after simplifying because multiplication is associative)
- `1 * 2 * foo(5, List(-2, 2))`: the list is non-empty, so the second match clause matches and the result is
- `1 * 2 * -2 * foo(4, List(2))`: the list is non-empty, so the second match clause matches and the result is
- `1 * 2 * -2 * 2 * foo(3, Nil)`: the list is empty, so the first match clause matches and the result is
- `1 * 2 * -2 * 2 * 3`: which when multiplied out is
- `-24`

For some people, the logic of this function would be better expressed as

```
def foo(n: Int, ls: List[Int]): Int =
  if (ls.isEmpty) n
  else ls.head * foo(n - 1, ls.tail)
```

It could also be expressed, after a little algebraic manipulation as

```
(n - ls.length) * ls.product
```

Although for a `List` that will be slower than the recursive implementations (as `.length` and `.product` will each fully traverse the list).

Comment: There are also implementations which are tail-recursive (i.e. the compiler will turn them into a loop) and which use `foldLeft`: both require an auxiliary value.

Answer (score 1):

I have added println's to your original answer which prints execution stack trace exactly like Levi has explained in his answer. This trick should help with other recursive examples to understand execution flow:

```scala
def printMul(xs: List[Int]) = if (xs.nonEmpty) xs.mkString(" * ") + " * " else ""

def foo(n: Int, ls: List[Int], prev: List[Int] = Nil): Int =
  ls match {
    case Nil =>
      println(s"${printMul(prev)}$n")
      n
    case hd :: tl =>
      println(s"${printMul(prev)}$hd * foo(${n - 1}, $tl)")
      hd * foo(n - 1, tl, prev :+ hd)
  }

// ====== Output ======
/*

1 * foo(6, List(2, -2, 2))
1 * 2 * foo(5, List(-2, 2))
1 * 2 * -2 * foo(4, List(2))
1 * 2 * -2 * 2 * foo(3, List())
1 * 2 * -2 * 2 * 3

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo` terminates when the list passed as parameter `ls` is `Nil` (empty).

Every time `foo` is called, `ls` has its head (`hd`) and tail (`tl`) extracted via pattern matching. The head is multiplied against the next `foo` call which takes only the tail of the list (as well as subtracting the `n` value by 1.

When `foo(7,List(1,2,-2,2))` is evaluated, the next step is `1 * foo(6, List(2, -2, 2))` and so on...